# Colorbar size on Octave

Tags: plot, octave, colorbar

I'm trying to set the colorbar size on a figure printed on pdf, but doesn't work.

there are the rows of my code:

```
figure(1, "paperunits", "centimeters", "papertype", "a4", "paperorientation", "portrait", "paperposition", [0, 8.7, 19, 19]);
plot(ext(:,1), ext(:,2), "color", "k");
hold;
axis([x_range(1), x_range(2), y_range(1), y_range(2)], "equal", "off");
plot(int(:,1), int(:,2), "color", "k");
colormap("viridis");
scatter(pnt_rl(:,1), pnt_rl(:,2), 8, v*3.6, "filled");
colorbar("EastOutside");
title("Speed [km/h]");
print Figure1.pdf
```

The colorbar is the same size of the plot, in the screen, but much bigger on the printed pdf.
I read many times the guide, but I cannot solve this problem

Comment: error: 'ext' undefined near line 2, column 2

Comment: ext, int, x_range, y_range and pnt_rl are all vector that I don't post here.